# Building an app using gradle with jenkins in docker

Tags: jenkins, gradle, docker

I want to build my project with gradle.
To achieve this I have a  docker file with installation details of Gradle and Java and I am trying to run it as a Jenkins job.
I have the docker file in the root of my project and I have configured Jenkins to pull code from git.
I have installed Jenkins in docker too..

But I am not sure hot to run the docker file as a Jenkins Job and then run Gradle as a Jenkins Job.

Comment: See: https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/niaquinto/gradle/

Comment: or https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/applicationa/jenkins-slave-java-mvn-gradle/ or https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/applicationa/jenkins-slave-java-gradle/

Answer (score 2):

These would be a checking list you would need to follow:

- install the jenkins git plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin
- install the jenkins gradle plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin
- in your gradle build, add the gradle docker plugin that will allow you to handle the dockerfile. Make sure you have the docker client installed on the build machine https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin
- create a task in your gradle build that will publish the artifact in the docker image (make this task dependent on the build task)
- fire this task from jenkins. After the image is built, you should push the docker container image to a local docker repository or you can start the container directly.

Comment: I've created a POC that will use the gradle docker plugin to create an image, build it, instantiate the container and run the app in the container. You just have to call the gradle startAppContainer task from jenkins.
https://github.com/nucatus/gradle-docker-poc